# Why can't I assign lambda to the variable using ternary operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

When I assign anonymous function to the variable using ternary operator with the true condition, I can call the variable as a normal function.

```
>>> a = lambda x, y: x + y if True else lambda x, y: x * y
>>> a(1, 2)
3
```

But when the condition is false and the function to be assigned is after the word `else`, I get something like this. I have no idea what mechanisms stand behind such a weird behaviour. Is there any syntax nuances? Or any possibility to use ternary operator in cases like this one?

```
>>> a = lambda x, y: x + y if False else lambda x, y: x * y
>>> a(1, 2)
<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x10916aee0>
```

Comment: You mean `(lambda x, y: x + y) if True else (lambda x, y: x * y)` but you have `lambda x, y: (x + y if True else lambda x, y: x * y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use parentheses to indicate your meaning.

You mean

```
(lambda x, y: x + y) if True
else (lambda x, y: x * y)
```

but you have

```
lambda x, y:
    (x + y if True
     else lambda x, y: x * y)
```

The `... if ... else ...` operator has higher precedence than `lambda`. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence.